# The screen is too small

Tags: virtualbox, display, screen, display-resolution

I am using Virtual Box 5.0.0(Windows Vista) to run Ubuntu 14.04. The screen is **too small (640x480)** but the screen **can up to 1280x768**. *How can I resizing it?*

Comment: I wrote some step by step instructions with images that can be found here - https://superuser.com/a/1557176/706430

Answer (score 16):

You need to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions into Ubuntu.  This gives a few benefits, including resizing the Ubuntu screen to match the host window.

Start the VM, then select from the VirtualBox menus:

> **Devices ⇒ CD/DVD Devices ⇒ VBoxGuestAdditions.iso**

Then follow the instructions.

Comment: Note that you may also need to increase video RAM for the VM to get desired results

Comment: Seems obvious, but also keep in mind to change the resolution in the guest OS.

Comment: Under Virtualbox 6.0.4 on MacOS, the menu would be: Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image

Comment: In version 6.0 of Virtual Box the menu is Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD image...  then you will have to authenticate for the installtion to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Setting-->Display-->Scale Factor, change it

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my PC recently. This is my solution;

Go to the Ubuntu machine:

> **Settings ⇒ Display ⇒ Graphics controller ⇒ Choose (VBoxSVGA or VBoxSVGA)**

My original settings which caused the problem was `VMSVGA`.

This solution worked on my PC. I cannot guarantee that it will work on yours.